# jQuery slider: color changing menu won't sync with the rest of the slider

Tags: jquery, css, slider

So I have made a slider that has sliding images and a menu that slides with it.

**It works like this:**
The images slide to the left and the menu moves with it so that the menu button that is connected to the current image is always on the far left.
And in addition to that the menu changes color depending on which slide is active.
**And it's here the problems start:**
If I just let it slide by it self it works like it should but if I press any buttons in the menu and the next time it slides automatically the colors of the menu gets offset.
The button to the far left in the menu should always be yellow and the other buttons should get a brighter gray as further away they are from the yellow one.

Here is a link to the slider: http://server.patrikelfstrom.se/rcane/slider/
Javascript: http://server.patrikelfstrom.se/rcane/slider/slider.js
CSS: http://server.patrikelfstrom.se/rcane/slider/slider.css

I know it's a big question but I can't figure out how I'm supposed to fix this. Please help. Thanks.

*(I'm using jquery 1.3 because the site that I'm building this for use that. (I know old and crappy, but I can't change))*

Answer (score 0):

i cant find it too but to get to a point the bug must be triggered somewhere in the click function:

```
jQuery('#slider-menu-content .slider-menu-item a').click(function(e) {
    var id = jQuery(this).parent('li').attr('class').match(/\d/);
    moveSlide(id, id);
    moveMenu(id, id);
    interval = resetSliderInterval(interval);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

it seems like its breaking up the positions if the autoslider starts again with sliding.
try to **reset somehow the resetSliderInterval function** if you start clicking around with each click.

Comment: Hm... I call resetSliderInterval on each click and movement so It should update count and take the latest imo :/